# What is special use of comma ( , ) operator while running "Jq" in command line?

Tags: jq

Here is the sample code,

```
echo '{"x" : 1}' | jq '. , .'
```

The output of the above command is this:
{
    "x" : 1
}
{
    "x" : 1
}

I am beginner and didn't find much information about comma (, ) operator while
running with "jq".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for jq by typing:

```
man jq
```

There is a paragraph on the use of the comma ,

```
,

If two filters are separated by a comma, then the input  will  be  fed
into both and there will be multiple outputs: first, all of the outputs
produced by the left expression, and then all of the outputs produced
by the right. For instance, filter .foo, .bar, produces both the "foo"
fields and "bar" fields as separate outputs.
```

:-)

Comment: Also from the man page: 'Once you understand the "," operator, you can look at jq's array syntax
       in a different light: the expression [1,2,3] is not  using  a  built-in
       syntax for comma-separated arrays, but is instead applying the [] oper-
       ator (collect results) to the expression 1,2,3  (which  produces  three
       different results).' Even `1`, `2`, and `3` are simply filters that ignore their input and produce the appropriate numeric values, with `,` joining the results.

Comment: See also: [Comma: ,](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Comma:,) in the jq manual.  Note however there are a few places where `,` behaves slightly differently (e.g. destructuring patterns and object constructors).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple filters in `jq` are separated by a comma. `. , .` duplicates the output because it means two times *the current context*.